# How to write to Azure Blob with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-batch, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write a line-by-line csv to a Azure Blob with Spring Batch.

Autowiring the Azure Storage:

```
@Value("${azure.storage.ConnectionString}")
private String connectionString;

@Value("${azure.storage.container.name}")
private String containerName;


@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo> writer(
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['marketName']}") String marketName,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['startDate']}") String startDate,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['YYYY-MM']}") String yearMonth
) {
    // Create writer instance
    FlatFileItemWriter<Pojo> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    String fullPath = yearMonth + "/" +  marketName + "/" +
            marketName + "_" + startDate;

    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString)
            .containerName(containerName)
            .buildClient();

    BlobClient blob = container.getBlobClient(fullPath);

    // Set output file location
    writer.setResource((Resource) blob);

    // All job repetitions should "append" to same output file
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

    // Name field values sequence based on object properties
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Pojo>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Pojo>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] {
                            "market",
                            "epsg",
                            "xbin",
                            "ybin",
                            "latitude",
                            "longitude",
                            "totalDownlinkVol",
                            "totalUplinkVol"
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return writer;
}
```

Then I get the Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.writer' defined in class path resource [com/example/dbreader/configuration/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter]: Factory method 'writer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Spring is complaining that I cannot cast the Blob to a Resource.

Does anybody knows how do I point the Azure Blob Storage in the Spring Batch Writer?

thx, Markus.

Comment: How about writing all content to a local .csv file and upload this file to azure blob after writing and remove the file after uploading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemWriter` requires a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` to write data. If the API you use does not implement this interface, it is not usable with the `FlatFileItemWriter`. You need to provide a `Resource` implementation for Azure or look for an library that implements it, like the [Azure Spring Boot Starter Storage client library for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-storage).

Comment: I am trying your suggestion and going thru the link you sent. Now I am getting a NullPointerException when autowiring the Azure BlobServiceClientBuilder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622916/spring-is-failling-to-autowire-azure-storage-blob