# Spring is failling to Autowire Azure Storage Blob

Tags: spring, azure, spring-batch, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a Spring Batch that has a writer to an Azure Storage Blob.

I am using this Azure/Spring Dependency:

azure-spring-boot-starter-storage 3.4.0

On my application properties I have:

```
azure.storage.accountName=myAccount
azure.storage.accountKey=myKey
```

Then inside my BatchConfig class I autowired the AZ Storage:

```
@Autowired
private BlobServiceClientBuilder blobServiceClientBuilder;

private final BlobServiceAsyncClient blobServiceAsyncClient = blobServiceClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient();
```

Now when I start my application, I am getting a NullPointerException because the BlobServiceClientBuilder cannot be instantiated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.dbreader.configuration.BatchConfig.<init>(BatchConfig.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.dbreader.configuration.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58787751.<init>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
```

What am I doing wrong when autowiring the Azure Blob Bean?

One more thing I am using the Spring Resource to instantiate a blob file:

```
@Value("blob://{containerName}/" + "#{stepExecutionContext['marketName']}")
private Resource blobFile;
```

Comment: you might have to create bean and give it to the framework and not create instance and keep it with you, also the error seems in BatchConfig #55

Comment: You need to first make sure to correctly configure Azure Storage resource: Here is a link to the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-boot-starter-storage-readme. Please remove ` + "#{stepExecutionContext['marketName']}"` and see if this fixes the issue. I'm suspecting that the key `marketName` is empty in `stepExecutionContext`.  Please share the code of your `BatchConfig` class to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: We recently open-sourced a simple Spring Boot based utility library to upload blob data. Take a look for auto wiring options - https://github.com/scoperetail-io/commons-azure-storage

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue . Looks like its a mistake from documentation.
Azure.storage.blob-endpoint property is mandatory for blobClient and optional for fileClient. Add

```
Azure.storage.blob-endpoint= https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net
```

to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. finally I found that the buildClient() method couldn't be put in global or constructor. just put it in the GET/POST method, it'll work. FYR.

```
   @Autowired
private BlobServiceClientBuilder blobServiceClientBuilder;

private BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;



@GetMapping
public String readBlobFile() throws IOException {
    blobServiceClient = blobServiceClientBuilder.buildClient();
    AzureStorageResourcePatternResolver storageResourcePatternResolver = new AzureStorageResourcePatternResolver(blobServiceClient);
```